# Instance of Object to bind and manipulate it?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I want to display an instance that the user can select by using a combobox. The combobox get all entries from a `ObservableCollection<string> Names {get;set;}` with a binding.

What is the best way to display all properties of this instance with a binding?

My idea was to create a `ObservableCollection<Foo> Bar {get;set;}`.
Now the user choosed on entry inside the combobox. 
With the selected name I will search the instance with this name in `ObservableCollection<Foo> Bar {get;set;}` and copy it into a new instance `Foo TMPBar {get;set;}`. 
And this instance should be binded to the GUI.

Is that a good solution way?

Comment: Just use the `SelectedItem` property of the ComboBox. It already returns the selected `Foo` instance. No need to copy anything.

Comment: @Clemens The problem is the ComboBox only displays the names - from a `ObservableCollection`. Inside this `OberservableCollection` are only names. After choosing a name I want to search the correct instance inside  `ObservableCollection<Foo> Bar {get;set;}`. Is that the correct way?

Comment: Bind the ComboBox's `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<Foo>` and set its `DisplayMemberPath` to the appropriate name property of your Foo class.

Comment: The best solution is as @Clemens described: Bind `ObservableCollection<Foo>` to the `ItemSource`. The property `DisplayMemberPath` at the `ComboBox` is the name of the property in `Foo` which will be displayed as the text in the `ComboBox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than bind the combo box to a list of names, bind to a list of the actual objects and use the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the ComboBox to just show the name.

Then you've got direct access to the the object via the `SelectedItem` property.

So you'll need:

```
public ObservableCollection<Foo> Bar { get; set; }
public Foo Selected { get; set; }
```

in your view model, and:

```
<ComoboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Bar}"
           DisplayMemberPath=Name
           SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}" />
```

in your view.